# REST API pagination and client side caching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, caching, microformats

Using Rails, I have a HTTP endpoint that returns an array of the records (media files) linked to a playlist in JSON format.

The client side caching is done by checking the date of the playlist and generate the appropriate etag with Rails' `stale?(@playlist)` in the `/playlist/id/media_files.json` response.

Now I would like to implement pagination but trying to keep, to some degree, client side caching.

Is there some smart approach I can take or am I forced to respond to all requests with a 200 and always pumping data down the wire to the clients?

How do you handle pagination (server, client) caching in API?

Answer (score 1):

When I use page caching in Rails and I have to deal with pagination I just put the page in the URL.  So, if for example, I have a resource that looks like this:

```
resource :users
```

I change it for (add a new line):

```
get 'users/page/:page', to: 'users#index'
resource :users
```

I am not sure what client side you are using, but the idea here is that you want to cache individual pages separately. Since the page is now part of the URL, you have each page cached and your problem should be solved :)